# Update Table field when different field is updated with specific value - MS Access

Tags: ms-access

I know this is probably a simple question/answer but here we go. I am trying to have a record field updated in MS Access when another one of the record fields is updated with "closed". Essentially, I am trying to make a field that will update the column "Date closed" with a timestamp, when the status is set to "closed". I believe I need to use a macro for this, but I can't seem to get my code right. Am I on the right track here, or am I not even close?

I have selected "After edit" macro and here is what my code looks like:

```
EditRecord

     IF [DBtable].[status] = "CLOSED"   THEN
        SetField
          name DBtable.closed_date
          value= Date()
     ENDIF
END EditRecord
```

Here is a screenshot, but wanted to keep name of database private:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Tf0Vb.png)

Comment: I'm not following the logic of this question.  Why not make this an AfterUpdate event on the Status field in your data entry form?  Or is the data not being updated via a form?

Comment: Good point. Agree should use AfterUpdate event of status control on form, whether code is macro or VBA is personal preference. I never have used table Data Macros.

Comment: I tested this DataMacro code and it did nothing. I have no idea why. Again, I don't use macros of any kind, only VBA. What is so sensitive about a table name you wanted it kept private?

Comment: most likely status is a string variable in the table (= "closed") so a quick but dirty solution would be to add date delimiters like ("= #" & Date() & "#" but now you still have to convert the string back to a date every time you need it.  Better to store a date in the table.  I don't use setField as there are many choices for updating records but setField requires an index indicating the row number in the recordset.  setField may default to the current row and still work, I don't know.

Comment: try this link: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/access/concepts/data-access-objects/modify-an-existing-record-in-a-dao-recordset

Comment: Thanks y'all. I used your advice and just did an AfterUpdate event with VB. I was hoping it would just populate when the status said closed, but this is much easier. appreciate your help!